# In Query " SELECT * FROM users WHERE Name=' ' -0||' ' AND Password='11' "

Tags: mysql, sql

In Query

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE Name=' ' -0||' ' AND Password='11'
```

In this statement what means expression **'-0||'** means, it shows all content of table?

Comment: This Query only work on mysql
I just wanted to know that what is use of -0

Comment: Buddy but I did it on my own please try at your own

Comment: This appears to be a clever sort of SQL injection attack.

Comment: yes but why this happening this same happens with +0 also

Comment: I am trying to figure this out.  Your question got downvoted because the query looks broken to the naked eye.  Next time give a better description.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a clever sort of SQL injection attack designed to return all records from the `users` table.  Your original query can be rewritten like the following:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE (Name=' ' -0)||(' ' AND Password='11')
```

Because of the order of operator precedence in MySQL, the unary minus (`-`) has the highest precedence, following by `AND`, and lastly `||`, which is `OR`.

This has the side effect that it creates a `WHERE` clause of the form `condition1 || condition2`, and one of the conditions will always be true.

The query which was intended by the server side engineers likely looked like this:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE Name='something' AND Password='11'
```

By inserting `' -0||'` for the username, it creates a `WHERE` clause which will return true for every row, returning the entire user table in the result set.

You can play around with the query using this Fiddle:

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/074eb0/7)